# Android : PopUp window like AZ Screen Recorder App

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio-2.2, android-popupwindow

As I am developing my first Android app, recording mobile screen using [this tutorial](https://github.com/chinmoyp/screenrecorder). Now I want to display my recorded video like following Pop-up window layout with share functionality of the AZ Screen Recorder in my android app.

[image]

How to implement the above functionality in Android Studio 2.2?

Answer (score 0):

After you are done recording the video you can start a new activity where all these share and other options. To make this activity as a popup over the android system all you have to do is set either of the following code in android manifest of that activity:

For Activity:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

For AppCombatActivity:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert"
```

Hope it helps!!